# Is it possible to easily work with .odt, .doc, .docx, .rtf, and other non-plain-text formats in Vim?

Tags: autocmd, load, word-processing, file-formats

Occasionally someone sends me a `.odt`, `.doc`, and `.docx` file; opening them in OpenOffice is always a pain because, well, OpenOffice.

Right now I use a variety of commandline tools (such as `odt2txt`) to convert these files to plain text, save the plain text to a temporary file, and then view (and maybe edit) it in Vim.

Can this be made easier? Perhaps something with autogroups? Or maybe there are better ways? I would like to just do:

```
$ vim file.odt
```

And have Vim take care of the converting for me?

Even better (bonus points) would be if I was also able to save the file (to `file.txt`), but that this would *not* be created until I do a write...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to add something like this to your vimrc:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.odt :%!odt2txt %
```

That will send the entire buffer through the `odt2txt` program after it's read in by vim, but only if the file name ends with `.odt`.

There's also the [textutil.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1432) plugin that says it can do what you're talking about for a few of those file types (but I haven't personally used it).

If you're willing to edit in something slightly more structured than plain text, like markdown, you could also use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to do the conversion:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.docx :%!pandoc -f docx -t markdown
autocmd BufWritePost *.docx :!pandoc -f markdown -t docx % > tmp.docx
```

I haven't actually tested these conversions, but they should work. You may need to use different tools depending on the file format.

Comment: does `autocmd BufReadPost *.docx :%!pandoc -f docx -t markdown` basically mean, that if I open a .docx file in vim, it will instead pass that file through `:%!pandoc -f docx -t markdown`, before displaying it on the VIM window?

Comment: @alpha_989 yes.